# python fastapi redirect and authenticate

Tags: fastapi

I'm trying to authenticate the user after visiting the registration link
(link example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm-email?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9F)

My code:

```
@app.get("/confirm-email", status_code=200, )
def confirm_email(
        token: str = fastapi.Query(..., min_length=64, max_length=256,
        db: Session = fastapi.Depends(database.get_db)):
    if user := crud.read_user_by(db, column='current_token', value=token):
        if user.created_datetime + timedelta(minutes=30) > datetime.now():  # TODO change minutes to days
            return fastapi.responses.RedirectResponse(
                url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/me",
                headers={"access_token": token, "token_type": "bearer"})
        else:
            raise fastapi.HTTPException(
                status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_410_GONE,
                detail="Confirmation link is expired")
    else:
        raise fastapi.HTTPException(
            status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Wrong token")


@app.get("/users/me") 
def read_users_me(token: str = fastapi.Depends(oauth2_scheme),
                  db: Session = fastapi.Depends(database.get_db)):
    try:
        return services.get_user_by_token(db=db, token=token)
    except Exception as e:
        raise fastapi.HTTPException(
            status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Could not validate credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
```

But every time I'm failing when trying to use `/users/me` endpoint (getting 401 error, UNAUTHORIZED).
Maybe I put the token in the wrong place or using wrong headers?

Answer (score 0):

If using OAuth 2.0 and wanting to set the `access_token` in a request, tipically, it goes into the `Authorization` header like the example in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1): `Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM` - in the example, `mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM` would be the value of the token.

It seems to me that you are accessing the `users/me` endpoint with the headers `access_token: [token value]` and `token_type: "bearer"`. Instead, I believe the following header should be set: `Authorization: Bearer [token value]`

Comment: @N Pinheiro Thanks for the answer but I can't currently accept your answer as I can't test it because the framework has additional restrictions and to be authorized - you anyway to fill email-password form (I'm not sure about this!)

Answer (score 0):

After a little researching, I figured out that `redirection` by specification can't have authorization headers (browser/client will just ignore it mainly). So even if headers are correct - it's nonsense. One possible solution to use URL.

Comment: I didn't uderstand what you meant by "One possible solution to use URL"